# c# using statements without semicolon

Tags: c#, ado.net, using

I found following code online:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
        con.Open();
        //
        // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
            reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
        }
        }
    }
```

can anyone explain me why using (SqlCommand ..)  doesn't end with semicolon. my second question is generally after using we have to have { } to indicate scope of that using variable why in this case it is missing? and how, when will it dispose command object?

Comment: The [`using` *statement*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) "Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects", different than the [`using` *directive*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Comment: That way you can dispose objects in a correct order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can anyone explain me why using (SqlCommand ..) doesn't end with semicolon

Because the using command will run exactly one block: the one that follows. That block can be one statement only. If you put a semicolon at the end it will do nothing (run an empty statement).

This is the same case with 'if' for example.

```
if(a==b)
   Console.Write("they are equal!");

Console.Write("I'm outside the if now because if only runes one block");
```

But

```
if(1==2);
Console.Write("I will always run because the if ends with a semicolon! (executes an empty statement)");
```

> my second question is generally after using we have to have { } to
>   indicate scope of that using variable why in this case it is missing?

It's not, look closer.

> and how, when will it dispose command object?

It will call object.Dispose() (if it's not null) when the block ends (even if it throws an exception).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the using construct doesn't require that the statement end in a semicolon.

the using construct automatically ensures that your object is disposed of properly.

if the {} are not present then the scope is the next statement.  in your case that's the entire block of using(SqlReader...) because it is scoped with {}

Answer (score 0):

> 1. can anyone explain me why using (SqlCommand ..) doesn't end with semicolon.

Keywords like Using, If, For and Foreach do not need a ; to mark the ending
because it has not ended! You will never find code like this useful.

```
If(true);//This is totally meaningless code
Console.WrtieLine("Hello world!");
```

> 2. my second question is generally after using we have to have { } to indicate scope of that using variable why in this case it is missing?

Because scope of the outer using block can be safely decided in this case.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
```

Similarly you can also write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("i = {0}, j ={1}",i, j));
    }
//i and j are no longer accessible from this line after
//because their scopes ends with the }
```

> 3. and how, when will it dispose command object?

The whole concept of using Statement is well explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/yh598w02.aspx)